# How to add all numbers in a single line of string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a line which have a few digits combined with some words.

```
      1       1       1 Old -> New
```

I want to add all numbers to a variable. 
May I know how to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want `a_variable` to be 3?

Comment: Yes. The logic should be add all 3 digits to a variable

Answer (score 2):

You can use RegEx to extract the numbers from the text, cast them to integers, add them to a list and sum over the list elements:

```
import re
text = '      1       1       1 Old -> New'   
sum([int(i) for i in re.findall('\d+', text)])
```

Comment: your regex will catch things like `blah123foo` -- not sure if the OP's intention was to sum these as well....

Answer (score 1):

```
text = '      1       1       1 Old -> New'
nums = []
for t in text.split() :
    try :
        nums.append( int(t) )
    except ValueError:
        pass

print( sum(nums) )

3
```